# Consider defining a bean of type repository in your configuration. Kotlin spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I'm trying to build and run spring boot app using kotlin language. I researched some similar questions but could not make my app build. Error output: Parameter 0 of constructor in com.github.raketa92.mailservice.service.EmailService required a bean of type 'com.github.raketa92.mailservice.repository.MailRepository' that could not be found. Consider defining a bean of type 'com.github.raketa92.mailservice.repository.MailRepository' in your configuration.
I found [github](https://github.com/bijukunjummen/coroutine-cities-demo) repository where this kind of code builds and runs successfully.

Here is my repository file:

```
interface MailRepository : CoroutineCrudRepository<Email, Long>{
@Query("SELECT * FROM email WHERE messageId = :messageId")
suspend fun getEmailByMessageId(messageId: Int): Email?

@Query("UPDATE email set statusId = :statusId where id = :id")
suspend fun updateStatus(statusId: Int, id: Long): Email
}
```

Here is my Service file:

```
package com.github.raketa92.mailservice.service

import com.github.raketa92.mailservice.model.Email
import com.github.raketa92.mailservice.repository.MailRepository
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service

@Service
class EmailService(
    private val  mailRepository: MailRepository,
    private val javaMailSender: JavaMailSender
    ) 
{
fun sendMail(email: Email) {
    val message = SimpleMailMessage()
    message.setSubject(email.subject)
    message.setText(email.message!!)
    message.setTo(email.to)
    message.setFrom("test@mail.com")
    javaMailSender.send(message)
    println("email sent")
}

suspend fun getAllEmails(): Flow<Email> = mailRepository.findAll()

suspend fun getEmailById(id: Long): Email? = mailRepository.findById(id)

suspend fun getEmailByMessageId(messageId: Int): Email? = mailRepository.getEmailByMessageId(messageId)

suspend fun createEmail(email: Email): Email = mailRepository.save(email)

suspend fun updateStatus(statusId: Int, id: Long): Email = mailRepository.updateStatus(statusId, id)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `EmailService` is a Spring `@Service`, so Spring will create an instance of it at start-up.

But its constructor needs a `MailRepository` instance.  And you haven't told it where to get one from, so it throws the runtime error you've seen.

The usual way to tell Spring about a repository interface is to annotate it as [`@Repository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Repository.html); Spring then knows to create an instance (of a synthetic subclass implementing) that interface.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried annotating repository with @Repository, but that didn't help, shows the same error.

Comment: Is your `MailRepository` in the same package as your top-level application class, or in a subpackage?  That's the hierarchy that Spring searches by default, so you'll either need to make sure the classes you need are in there, or tell it where to search (with one of the params to the `@SpringBootApplication` or related annotation on your top-level class).

Comment: repository file is in subpackage, but I also tried moving it to the same level as application class, still getting the same error. I wonder what kind of situations can cause this kind of error, maybe if I search in that direction, I can find something.